# Glade is not in Application Folder (Mac)

Tags: macos, glade

I have installed Glade on my mac with

```
$ brew install glade
```

But Glade is not listed in applications.
How do I start Glade on Mac?

Comment: Homebrew installs applications into its own folder (usually `/usr/local/cellar` IIRC), running from the command line via `glade-3` should work (as per the docs: https://developer.gnome.org/glade/stable/getting-started.html.en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same trouble so I've made a skeleton app 
around a (hard) link to the glade binary, with a few icons and an
install script (if you don't have glade or its not linked correctly)
thrown in for good measure.
if you installed through brew it should work, if not then
cd into the .app folder and run the glade_install.sh script:

```
you@yourmac # sh ./Contents/Resources/glade_install.sh;
```

**Release 1**
you can find the first release:
[On Github Here](https://github.com/sam-aldis/Glade-On-OSX/releases/tag/0.1a)

Its not codesigned at the moment so if you have a problem installing
it you 
may have to disable gatekeeper.

I Welcome pull requests and will try to fix any problems you have, just create an issue!

---

```css
.holder {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    animation: rotate 10s 1000;

}
.holder > div {
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 40px;
    word-break: break-word;
    transition: 0.5s;

}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
      transform: rotateZ(0deg);
    }
   100% {
      transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div><a href="https://github.com/sam-aldis?tab=repositories" target="__blank">Personal::Projects</a></div>
  <div><a href="https://github.com/ukjp-labs" target="__blank">ukjp-labs::Security</a></div>
  <div><a href="https://ukjp.app">ukjp.app</a></div>
  <div><a href="https://github.com/ukjp-open">UKJP::Public::Code</a></div>
</div>
```

[My Personal Projects](https://github.com/sam-aldis/)


[ukjp-labs](https://github.com/ukjp-labs)